# saving video giving Black Screen

Tags: javascript, webrtc, record

I   Am trying to save my my video but i keep getting a  black  video any reason a to why this could be happening
I have attached my code below for reference
i have kept the stat recording and stop recording button separate so that can use it late to bind other event-listeners

How would i go about  saving my video

Jquery Is initialized  above using jquery3

```
           <video autoplay id="videoElement"></video>
                <br>
            <button style="height: 90px;width: 200px" id="start">Start</button>
            <button style="height: 90px;width: 200px" id="stop">Stop</button>
        
            <a href="" id="download">download</a>
        
        
   <script>     
        $(function(){
            var sessionkey = ""
            var currentgesture = 4;
            var key = "";
        
         var width = 640;    // We will scale the photo width to this
          var height = 0;     // This will be computed based on the input stream
          var streaming = false;
          var constraints = {
                video: true,
                audio: false,
                width: {exact: 640}, 
                height: {exact: 480},
                frameRate: { ideal: 10, max: 12 } 
            }
        
         const video = document.querySelector('video');
           
        
        
        //Check For WebCam
        function hasGetUserMedia() {
          return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
        }
        
        if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
          runVideo()
        } else {
          alert('Not Supported! Please use another browser');
        }
        
        var chunks = []
         ;
        var mediaRecorder
        function runVideo(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
          then(async (stream) => {
            
           mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder(stream,{ mimeType: 'video/webm'})
        
            video.srcObject = stream;
            
        
        
        
           mediaRecorder.onstart = function(e) {
               chunks = []
            };
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
           
            chunks.push(e.data);
             console.log(chunks)
            };
             mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
             var blob = new Blob(chunks,{ 'type' : 'video/webm' });
             console.log(blob)
                downloadLink = document.getElementById('download');
              downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              downloadLink.download = 'acetest.webm';
                // socket.emit('radio', blob);
            };
            console.log(mediaRecorder)
          });
        }
        
        
        $("#start").click(function(){
         mediaRecorder.start()
         
        })
        $("#stop").click(function(){
        
             mediaRecorder.stop()
            
        })
        </script>
```

Comment: hey did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: I ended up sending images  every 100th of a second and stitching it on my python server made it easier cause processing the whole video was would have been to heavy for processing .......clients don't want to spend on big servers what to do :P     video output was fairly decent reduced framerate off-course but enough for my face recognition and gesture detection scripts to run  ----- no audio thou

Comment: thank you Reuben, your solution makes sense for your use case. i do need the whole video including the audio, i'll continue debugging and see if i can find a solution for this one

Comment: if you find a solution do let me know :P

Comment: after  spending quite some time on it, adding  codecs to the mmimetype solved the issue. mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9"

Comment: ohh haha guess ill use it for someother use case maybe when mobile net gets better in india...4g (more like 2g)